# What is `normal! zvzz` in vimscript?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, normal-mode

I found [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim/blob/1dcdb21db618055134cd611f4f5918f6d00a5df0/autoload/fzf/vim.vim#L823) the following command `normal! zvzz`

But I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `normal` command simulate keyboard input in normal mode. The `normal!` version ignore the custom mapping that could have been introduced such that its behavior does not depend on special customization or the presence of plugins.

`normal! zvzz` trigger the following two normal commnands: `zv` and `zz`

`zv` Open the fold to make the cursor line visible.

`zz` Center the screen on the cursor line.

From the help:

```
zv      View cursor line: Open just enough folds to make the line in
        which the cursor is located not folded.
```

```
z.      Redraw, line [count] at center of window (default
        cursor line).  Put cursor at first non-blank in the
        line.

zz      Like "z.", but leave the cursor in the same column.
        Careful: If caps-lock is on, this command becomes
        "ZZ": write buffer and exit!
```

Comment: I think an explanation of `:normal` is missing.